# 2013 Workflow missing when viewed from another PC

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, office-365

There is a similar year-old question with no accepted answer, so I though I would post this one with more detailed information.

I created some 2010 and 2013 workflows using SharePoint Designer 2013 on my office computer (My company is using SP Office 365). They work just fine. I can open and edit them as I please on Designer.

A co-worker is collaborating on the project and needs to be able to open and edit the workflows on he's own computer. When he opens the 2013 workflows and clicks on `"Edit Workflow"` he finds an empty workflow. But when he opens an 2010 workflow he can edit it just fine.

He created some 2013 workflows of his own and I was able to edit his workflows on my computer. So its not a two-way problem. The workflows I create cant be edited by anyone except me. We checked with a third co-worker and she cant edit my 2013 workflows neither, but 2010 are fine.

Does anyone have a clue where the source of the problem is? I could not find a solution anywhere on the web. I'm curious to see if anyone can replicate this problem.

Comment: check this one http://community.office365.com/en-us/f/148/t/237500.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was experiencing this problem as well with my co-workers. I believe this is a SharePoint designer bug. What you need to do is install the SharePoint designer update for each computer that is having this problem.

Here is the link below for the update:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/2837633

Answer (score 2):

For this kind of problem the @Murtaza Taz's answer is actually sufficient. But as you can see, the mentioned update is from December 10, 2013.

After playing more with the SharePoint Designer you could encounter more problems connected with Windows 8.

E.g. save and publish of workflow (WF) doesn't work sometimes, refreshing the WF, some actions in the WF doesn't work). But all of these are working on Windows 7 machine.

I solved it with installing the [Service Pack 1](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2817441) and then [newer update from August 2015](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3039732).

Answer (score 0):

Michal-husak's [service pack link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/description-of-microsoft-sharepoint-designer-2013-service-pack-1-sp1-54240f09-085c-1e3d-f41e-d53d1784e9ed) help me fixed my same issue, thank man.
the other update link is not availible now, but my workflow2013 condition issue was fixed by just install the service pack. thanks.